Ionic Angular TypeError: this.router.navigate is not a function
i am making a API call after the QR code scan,in the qr code row value my api url is present after the successfully fetching data i want to redirect to registration page but the following error is comming
TypeError: this.router.navigate is not a function
i checked all the module , routing module all imported , exported correctly
there is a question related to this and i checked all the fixes are already appiled
i imported all required module,component
here is my barcode-scanning.page.ts
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { Component, NgZone, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UntypedFormControl, UntypedFormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { DialogService } from 'src/app/services/dialog.service';
import { FilePicker } from '@capawesome/capacitor-file-picker';
import { BarcodeScanningModalComponent } from './barcode-scanning-modal.component';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';


import {
  Barcode,
  BarcodeFormat,
  BarcodeScanner,
  LensFacing,
} from '@capacitor-mlkit/barcode-scanning';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-barcode-scanning',
  templateUrl: './barcode-scanning.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./barcode-scanning.page.scss'],
})
@Injectable()
export class BarcodeScanningPage implements OnInit {
  public readonly barcodeFormat = BarcodeFormat;
  public readonly lensFacing = LensFacing;

  public formGroup = new UntypedFormGroup({
    formats: new UntypedFormControl([]),
    lensFacing: new UntypedFormControl(LensFacing.Back),
    googleBarcodeScannerModuleInstallState: new UntypedFormControl(0),
    googleBarcodeScannerModuleInstallProgress: new UntypedFormControl(0),
  });
  public barcodes: Barcode[] = [];
  public isSupported = false;
  public isPermissionGranted = false;
  

  constructor(
    private readonly dialogService: DialogService,
    private readonly ngZone: NgZone,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private navCtrl: NavController
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    BarcodeScanner.isSupported().then((result) => {
      this.isSupported = result.supported;
    });
    BarcodeScanner.checkPermissions().then((result) => {
      this.isPermissionGranted = result.camera === 'granted';
    });
    BarcodeScanner.removeAllListeners().then(() => {
      BarcodeScanner.addListener(
        'googleBarcodeScannerModuleInstallProgress',
        (event) => {
          this.ngZone.run(() => {
            console.log('googleBarcodeScannerModuleInstallProgress', event);
            const { state, progress } = event;
            this.formGroup.patchValue({
              googleBarcodeScannerModuleInstallState: state,
              googleBarcodeScannerModuleInstallProgress: progress,
            });
          });
        }
      );
    });
  }

  public async startScan(): Promise<void> {
    const formats = this.formGroup.get('formats')?.value || [];
    const lensFacing =
      this.formGroup.get('lensFacing')?.value || LensFacing.Back;
    const element = await this.dialogService.showModal({
      component: BarcodeScanningModalComponent,
      cssClass: 'barcode-scanning-modal',
      showBackdrop: false,
      componentProps: {
        formats: formats,
        lensFacing: lensFacing,
      },
    });
    element.onDidDismiss().then((result) => {
      const barcode: Barcode | undefined = result.data?.barcode;
      if (barcode) {
        this.processBarcode(barcode.rawValue);
      }
    });
  }

  private processBarcode(rawValue: string | undefined): void {
    if (!rawValue) {
      console.error('No barcode raw value to process');
      return;
    }

    const apiUrl = rawValue; 
    this.http.get(`${rawValue}`)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )
    
      .subscribe(response => {

        console.log('API response:', response);
        const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
          state: {
            data: response
          }
        };
        this.router.navigate(['/registration'], navigationExtras);
        


      });
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);
    return throwError('Something went wrong; please try again later.');
  }

  trackByBarcode(index: number, barcode: Barcode): string {
    return barcode.rawValue || index.toString();
  }

  public async readBarcodeFromImage(): Promise<void> {
    const { files } = await FilePicker.pickImages({ limit: 1 });
    const path = files[0]?.path;
    if (!path) {
      return;
    }
    const formats = this.formGroup.get('formats')?.value || [];
    const { barcodes } = await BarcodeScanner.readBarcodesFromImage({
      path,
      formats,
    });
    this.barcodes = barcodes;
  }

  public async scan(): Promise<void> {
    const formats = this.formGroup.get('formats')?.value || [];
    const { barcodes } = await BarcodeScanner.scan({
      formats,
    });
    this.barcodes = barcodes;
  }

  public async openSettings(): Promise<void> {
    await BarcodeScanner.openSettings();
  }

  public async installGoogleBarcodeScannerModule(): Promise<void> {
    await BarcodeScanner.installGoogleBarcodeScannerModule();
  }

  public async requestPermissions(): Promise<void> {
    await BarcodeScanner.requestPermissions();
  }

 
}

